# Knockout JS div binding pretty large text making the browser hung

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

I am seeming a browser hung issue, when using knockout to render a div with a very large string.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: datas">
    <div   data-bind="jsontext: Info"></div>
</div>
```

JS:
    datas is an array. It has only 1-2 elements in it. However, datas[0].Info is a string, which is very large, the length might be over 2 millions. When rendering the "Info" part, browser will hung.

Do you have any recommendation about how to workaround this issue? Seems DOM dov cannot render a very very large text. It would be good if you can recommend me some JS plugin so it can get the effect that only load the screen, if we need more, scroll up or down.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your binding? [I tested](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/0qgrd84m/) with 2million chars and it renders pretty quickly. Do you only render text or also HTML?

Comment: browser hung happens(mostly) if your are trying to bind a data via ajax call with `async` option set `false` other than this it should work fine .

Comment: Can you post your `jsontext` binding?

Comment: The answer is: 1. jsontext will hung when the text is very large. While data-bind="text: TextInfo" is OK.  2. I use some background logic to tell, if the length is > 20000, then us jasontext, otherwise I just show part of the content, and provide user a download function to see the full content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

1. jsontext will hung when the text is very large. While data-bind="text: TextInfo" is OK.
2. I use some background logic to tell, if the length is > 20000, then us jasontext, otherwise I just show part of the content, and provide user a download function to see the full content.